# Check if NSFont contains char

Tags: objective-c, unicode, nsfont

how could I check programmatically whether a NSFont contains a unicode character like '°'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, try this:

```
NSFont *font = [NSFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14.0];
NSCharacterSet *set = [font coveredCharacterSet];
if (![set characterIsMember:[@"°" characterAtIndex:0]]) {
    NSLog(@"Failed");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Success");
}
```

Comment: I tried it. Returns yes, because '°' will be drawn as another character, but it isn't in the font

Comment: I'm using "LCD_Solid" for example

Comment: You are right. I find out that the character is in the font, but it doesn't look like it. Very strange